# How to plot a boxplot using matplotlib with discontinuous y intervals on the y-axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following data set for which I need to generate the boxplot using matplotlib:

[92,92,92,92,92,92,92,92,92,92,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95,95]

but I want the y-axis of the box plot to be divided into the following intervals : [64000-277231 , 277231-380059, 380059-827581, 827581-1338451, 1338451-2593146, 2593146-4559994] and the x-axis to be divided in the intervals of 1, i.e [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. I am a newbie to matplotlib and have to get this job done, I referred this post as well. I wrote the following script to draw the box plot, but I am not able to achieve the above mentioned functionality using different matplotlib constructs like xticks, yticks and xlim and ylim.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

# agg backend is used to create the output file as a .png file
mpl.use('agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.suptitle('Bitrate vs Trials', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel("Bitrate")   
plt.xlabel("Trials")    
fig_instance = plt.figure(1 , figsize=(9,6))
ax_instance = fig_instance.add_subplot(111)
bp = ax_instance.boxplot(bitRateList)
# save the figure
fig_instance.savefig('a.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

How do I go about plotting the graph for above list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use log scale y-axis, you can try

```
ax_instance.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: I want the y-axes to be split up in the following intervals and the plot drawn using those intervals -  [64000-277231 , 277231-380059, 380059-827581, 827581-1338451, 1338451-2593146, 2593146-4559994]

Comment: @AnkitSablok I calculate the natural log values of your first several intervals, and the log results are close to linear values, so I thought it's log scale you ask for.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the log results are close to linear values", I am not able to get it

Comment: @AnkitSablok I mean [ln(64000), ln(277231), ln(380059), ln(827581), ln(1338451), ln(2593146), ln(4559994)] is like a linear series. Where did you get these numbers?

Comment: yes its a monotonically increasing sequence but I have arranged the data in order